# JAVA GAE: Process terminated because the machine was forced to shutdown

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My java application is running on GAE for a long time. Today the application has returned 500 and the appengine log just shows the message:

```
"Process terminated because the machine was forced to shutdown"
```

I am not able to find any documentation that explains the reasons for that message.

The only doc about shutdown lifecycle is https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown

```
Shutdown

The shutdown process might be triggered by a variety of planned and unplanned events, such as:

    You manually stop an instance.
    You deploy an updated version to the service.
    The instance exceeds the maximum memory for its configured instance_class.
    Your application runs out of Instance Hours quota.
    Your instance is moved to a different machine, either because the current machine that is running the instance is restarted, or App Engine moved your instance to improve load distribution.
```

Well, the only pausible reason is the last one, but yet, i am not convinced that message refers to "app engine moved your instance..."

My application config:

```
<instance-class>B4_HIGHMEM</instance-class>
<runtime>java8</runtime>
<basic-scaling>
    <max-instances>1</max-instances>
    <idle-timeout>1m</idle-timeout>
</basic-scaling>
```

Any idea?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why exactly it is happening in your GAE, however, according to the [App Engine Service Level Agreement](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/sla), the promised Monthly Uptime Percentage for GAE is *"at least 99.95%"*.

> "Monthly Uptime Percentage" means total number of minutes in a month,
> minus the number of minutes of Downtime suffered from all Downtime
> Periods in a month, divided by the total number of minutes in a month.

Therefore, this *could* be an expected behaviour, however, if you believe it is happening more often, I'd recommend you to contact the GCP technical [support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) for a more detailed inspection.

---

Also, you might want to increase the *[max-instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref)* parameter in your app's configuration as more instances will help in better load process, thus if one instance fails the others will keep working.

Answer (score 0):

When an App Engine instance is unable to process a request, and therefore crashes/dies, 500s errors will appear. Chances are that the GAE is handling [long-running requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-handled#specifying_a_request_deadline) that might take a while to complete.

A bit of context, App Engine creates sandbox instances when it serves the requests, sometimes these instances may be subject to crash, change or shutdown, then other errors may appear eventually.

While this issue is not expected to happen frequently, it can be caused by different reasons. I would recommend to look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown) that you shared previously and double check for the items on the list, as well as for long-lasting requests.